resolving 'dyld' error when running python--version and addressing homebrew conflicts
I encounter the following error when running the command python--version: dyld[5952] library not loaded.../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/Python'(no such file, not in dyld cache) [1] 5952 abort python --version
Problem statement : The error suggests that the system's dynamic linker cannot locate the required Python library.This might result from dependency conflicts, missing files, or broken symlinks related to Python and Homebrew-managed tools like AWS CLI.
Steps I Tried

Relinking AWS CLI:

Ran brew link --overwrite awscli, which warned that AWS CLI was already linked.

Tried brew unlink awscli && brew link awscli, but the error persisted.



Reinstalling AWS CLI:

Executed brew install awscli and later brew reinstall awscli, but neither resolved the issue.


Running Homebrew Cleanup:

Used brew cleanup awscli, but the system advised setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP to disable automatic cleanup.



What I'd Want

Resolve the dyld error and ensure Python commands work correctly.

Fix any underlying dependency or configuration conflicts between Python and AWS CLI.

Restore a functional Python environment and ensure seamless integration with AWS CLI.


Detailed, step-by-step guidance is appreciated to permanently address the issue and avoid repetitive troubleshooting loops.
